# Enforcing wildcard constraints in expansion

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, snakemake

I want to collect all files matching the regex `^fs_node\d+\.xyz$`, but I don't know how to write the expansion so that the glob uses the constraint.  Right now,

```
wildcard_constraints:
    nodeidx = "\d+",

rule all:
    input:
        expand("fs_node{i}.xyz",
               i=glob_wildcards("fs_node{nodeidx}.xyz").nodeidx)
```

produces output that also matches files with `irc`, which I don't want:

```
    input: fs_node37_irc.xyz, fs_node41_irc.xyz, fs_node32.xyz, fs_node10.xyz, fs_node43.xyz, fs_node2.xyz, fs_node30_irc.xyz, fs_node16.xyz, fs_node45.xyz, fs_node23_irc.xyz, fs_node2_irc.xyz, fs_node44_irc.xyz, fs_node33_irc.xyz, fs_node35.xyz, fs_node1.xyz, fs_node28_irc.xyz, fs_node42.xyz, fs_node15_irc.xyz, fs_node12_irc.xyz, fs_node35_irc.xyz, fs_node42_irc.xyz, fs_node44.xyz, fs_node31.xyz, fs_node17_irc.xyz, fs_node8_irc.xyz, fs_node43_irc.xyz, fs_node15.xyz, fs_node5_irc.xyz, ...
```

How does one properly enforce (global) wildcard constraints in expansions?  It's global because also gets used in other locations.

Comment: I just saw that this is still a known problem: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/482

Comment: As far as I know, this is a limitation of glob_wildcards: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `glob_wildcards` is not flexible enough. I would explicitly list all files, select those you want to keep with some regex, extract the variable part `nodeidx` and use that as wildcard. Not tested:

```
import os
import re

listdir = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

nodeidx = []
for x in listdir:
    if re.match('^fs_node\d+\.xyz$', x):
        idx = re.sub('^fs_node', '', re.sub('\.xyz$', '', x))
        _ = int(idx) # sanity check
        nodeidx.append(idx)

wildcard_constraints:
    nodeidx = '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in nodeidx])

rule all:
    input:
        expand("fs_node{nodeidx}.xyz", nodeidx= nodeidx)
```

Comment: This is the approach I use, too.

Comment: I needed to do `_ = int(idx)`, since one of the matches is the number zero, which is desired behavior. But this works.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon good point about the number zero!

Comment: @dariober Of course I wanted to make an edit, but the suggested edits queue is full?!